# Pusher implementation in React, losing the context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pusher

I'm doing a basic implementation of Pusher, here's the relevant piece:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState();

useEffect(() =>
{
    //Fetching the messages from the API
    fetchMessages().then(fetchedMessages => setMessages(fetchedMessages));

    //Subscribing to a Pusher event in case of new messages
    pusherChannel.bind(EVENT_MESSAGE_SENT, (data) => 
    {
        //Here, "messages" is empty, even when it has been filled by the API already
        setMessages([...messages, data.message]);
    });

}, []);
```

So, I get the messages from the API and then listen for new messages through Pusher.

The problem I'm having is that inside the callback of `pusherChannel.bind`, the variable `messages` is empty, even when it has been filled by the API already.

Maybe the callback sends a copy of `messages` (and the entire callback function) instead of a reference? Anyways, I don't know how to handle updating the messages using that callback.

I've seen that the [bind](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events) method can take a third, "context", parameter, but I don't know how to implement it in hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I’ve splitted one useEffect to two, add one variable `isInit` that set to true after fetch init array of messages, add useCallback.

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState();
const [isInit, setIsInit] = useState(false);
const handleMessageSent = useCallback((data) => {
  setMessages(prevState => ([...prevState, data.message]));
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  fetchMessages().then((fetchedMessages) => {
    setMessages(fetchedMessages);
  }).finally(() => {
    setIsInit(true);
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isInit) {
    return;
  }

  pusherChannel.bind(EVENT_MESSAGE_SENT, handleMessageSent);

  return () => {
    pusherChannel.unbind(EVENT_MESSAGE_SENT, handleMessageSent);
  };
}, [isInit, handleMessageSent]);
```